# Is there any event which Fires when observes that a node from TreeList had the check mark checked from code?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

I have a part of code which analyzes a list with checked nodes ID's, and checks into the a TreeList existing ID's. (*I'm using a **[XtraTreeList](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2434)** control*)

I want to calculate amount for each checked node, and I just though to make this when the node is checked.

Is there any event which observes that a node from TreeList was checked from code (*programmatic*)?

Cause if I check/uncheck a node with the mouse, or with the keyboard **BeforeCheckNode** and **AfterCheckNode** events takes Fire, but when i check the node from code - they don't fires.

```
foreach (TreeListNode item in tln) {
    var nodeID = (this.tlServices.GetDataRecordByNode(item) as __ServiceInfo).ID;
    if (svc.Select(value => value.Model.service.id).Contains(nodeID)) {
        item.Checked = true;
    }
    else if (item.HasChildren) {
        this.FindNode(item.Nodes, svc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it is your code.  So just fire your own event or call the event handler directly.

Comment: The fact is that i need to calculate the amount after this TreeList is  designed.  I want to call the event from another class, when makes initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [TreeList.NodeChanged](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_NodeChangedtopic) event:

```
void treeList1_NodeChanged(object sender, NodeChangedEventArgs e) {
    if(e.ChangeType == NodeChangeTypeEnum.CheckedState) { 
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: @meorfi: You are always welcome! Next time, please use the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/support/center) to ask a questions or report issues, because there is no guarantee of DevExpress involvement when you use the communities, newsgroups or other communication channels.

Answer (score -1):

AfterCheckNode is the event.

```
private void _tree_AfterCheckNode(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.NodeEventArgs e)
    { TreeListNode node = e.Node as TreeListNode;}
```